# How to increase fighting stats of a player without increasing HP?

Tags: game-design, balance

I'm currently making a simple game that requires a fighting system. The game consists of many (more than 100) levels that the player needs to go through to get to the end. In each level you get to fight creatures and monsters, and you evolve your skills by doing so (there are also other ways to do that but they're not relevant for the purpose of this post). The problem I'm having is that when the player reaches the higher levels, the fights become very hard to balance:

To calculate the damage the player does to the enemy, I was basing it on the player's fighting skill (which goes up with each fight) and the opponent's fighting skill (which is based on the level). However, if I make it so the damage is proportional to the ratio of the skills, when both skills are high, neither of them will do much damage. On the other hand, if I base it on the difference of these skills, a player with less stats than a monster can't to any damage to it (which is not what I want, as some monsters may have more fighting skills but you have more health, and vice-versa).

My question is if there's any easy way to calculate the damage that would scale well when both parties are very strong.

Comment: Does my answer to this question help you? [RPG Formula - Attack and defense](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129319/rpg-formula-attack-and-defense/129322#129322). If not, please post the functions you are currently using to calculate damage and the ranges of the input variables for it.

Comment: What confuses me about this question is "if I make it so the damage is proportional to the ratio of the skills, when both skills are high, neither of them will do much damage" combined with "How to increase fighting stats of a player without increasing HP?". 200/200 is 1, and 2/2 is 1, and 1 is a decent amount of damage if a character always has 5 HP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the right way to do this.

But:

1. For balancing you can use [Machinations](https://machinations.io/), this is an interactive tool and now it's free. It's interesting alternative for balancing tables.
2. Maybe analyzing the fighting system (especially system of counter picks and balancing on different levels) of Pokemon game series can help you. Probably, if you have several types of fighters in your game and, for example, as fire pokemon has bonuses in battle with water pokemon, swordsman can have increased stats or more critical hit probability in battle with archer.
3. Final Fantasy 7 has unusual progress system: when you upgrade the player, you get material orbs. Each orb affects on different stats, but anytime you can shift them and turn your warrior player into support player or mage and vise versa. So to win the battle you need to choose orbs properly.